# I just purchased a used LEGO Studios set and had some extra pieces that don't belong

Tags: piece-information

Can anyone tell me what set they might be from?

[image: front]

backside:

[image: back]

Answer (score 3):

It's tough to predict where such a small number of pieces came from, but some are likely from the Hydronauts theme, specifically [Hydro Crystallisation Station (6199)](http://brickset.com/sets/6199-1/Hydro-Crystallisation-Station):

[image: 6199]

This set includes the chromed headgear with studs on the back as well as the printed tile that is already attached to the back of yours.

The minifig utensils are likely from [Mobile Outpost (6520)](http://brickset.com/sets/6520-1/Mobile-Outpost):

[image: 6520]

Here are links to the sets that these parts appear in if you'd like to explore this more:

- [3069 - Tile 1 x 2 with Copper and White Circuitry, Red Rectangle and 4 Squares Pattern](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpa2&in=S)
- [71598 - Chrome Blue Minifig, Headgear Helmet with 2 Studs on Back](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=71598&colorID=52&in=A)
- [6041 - Trans-Neon Green Propeller 3 Blade 3 Diameter](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6041&colorID=16&in=A)
- [2569 - Trans-Neon Green Antenna Whip 8H](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2569&colorID=16&in=A)
- [6040 - Black Propeller Housing](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6040&colorID=11&in=A)
- [30193 - Dark Gray Minifig, Utensil Ice Pick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30193&colorID=10&in=A)
- [3837 - Dark Gray Minifig, Utensil Shovel (Round Stem End)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3837&colorID=10&in=A)

Comment: Wow...that's amazing how you can do that.  Is that just from your general knowledge or do you have a way to search?  I couldn't see the numbers on the lego pieces and didn't even know what to call them to search for them.  Thank you for such detailed information...that's amazing :).

Comment: Thanks :) Once you have a pretty good understanding of how parts are organized on sites like Bricklink, it's not really too hard to determine what sets they come from.

Answer (score 1):

The trans neon green helmet on the right of the first pic appears to be from any of the [Aquazone, Aquaraiders I, Hydronauts, or possibly even Time Cruisers](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x41&colorID=16&in=A).

It's a start... :)